# Установка своих приложений на Android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите почему так: моё приложение, которое я написал в android studio, не устанавливается по пути и не создаёт там пакеты: внутренняя память/Android/data. Или только приложения с playmarketa там свои пакеты оставляют?

Comment: Как вы определили что не устанавливается? Может оно устанавливается, но девайс нерутован и вы просто не можете видеть содержимое папки?

Comment: По этому пути приложения **могут** писать свои файлы во время выполнения, а при установке туда ничего не пишется.